# StableName changes for no specific reason

Tags: haskell, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to implement the HashLife algorithm in Haskell. I am taking inspiration from http://dotat.at/prog/life/hslife.hs . Tony Finch uses Stable names as suggested in "Stretching the storage manager".

Imports, Types aliases and definitions, instances:
The Hash function uses the stablename of the node children

```
import qualified Data.HashTable.IO             as HT
import           System.IO.Unsafe
import           System.Mem.StableName
import           Data.Hashable
import           System.Mem.Weak
import           Control.Monad

type Table val = HT.CuckooHashTable Key (Weak val)
type Level = Int
type Key = Int
type Cons = QuadCell -> IO QuadCell

newtype NodeInfo = NodeInfo { level :: Level }
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data QuadCell = Dead | Alive | Node !NodeInfo !QuadCell !QuadCell !QuadCell !QuadCell
  deriving Eq

instance Hashable QuadCell where
  hashWithSalt _ (Node (NodeInfo i) a b c d) = unsafePerformIO $ do
    a' <- hashStableName <$> makeStableName a
    b' <- hashStableName <$> makeStableName b
    c' <- hashStableName <$> makeStableName c
    d' <- hashStableName <$> makeStableName d
    return $ i + a' * 3 + b' * 5 + c' * 7 + d' * 9
  hashWithSalt _ _ = error "Received Leaf in hashWithSalt"

instance Show QuadCell where
  show n@(Node (NodeInfo i) a b c d)
         | n == alive = "Alive:" ++ show (hash n)
         | n == dead = "Dead:" ++ show (hash n)
         | otherwise = "Node"
                          ++ "("
                          ++ show a
                          ++ ", "
                          ++ show b
                          ++ ", "
                          ++ show c
                          ++ ", "
                          ++ show d
                          ++ ")"
```

I now generate all possible level-0/1/2 Nodes of the quadtree to save up memory and speed up things on the long term.

```
dead, alive :: QuadCell
dead = Node (NodeInfo 0) Dead Dead Dead Dead
alive = Node (NodeInfo 0) Alive Alive Alive Alive

sq0, sq1, sq2 :: [QuadCell]
sq0 = [alive, dead]
sq1 = [ Node (NodeInfo 1) a b c d | a <- sq0, b <- sq0, c <- sq0, d <- sq0 ]
sq2 = [ Node (NodeInfo 2) a b c d | a <- sq1, b <- sq1, c <- sq1, d <- sq1 ]
```

Then I insert everything in a HashTable and for debugging purpose, i'll log the inserts

```
logging = appendFile "./logs" . (++ "\n")

memoInsert
  :: (Hashable n, Hashable v, Show n, Show v)
  => Table v
  -> n
  -> v
  -> IO ()
memoInsert tbl key val = logging ("Inserting " ++ show key ++ " -> " ++ show val) >> mkWeak key val Nothing >>= HT.insert tbl (hash key)

memoize = error "Not implemented"

consTable :: IO Cons
consTable = do
  table <- HT.new
  let add q = memoInsert table q q
  mapM_ add (sq0 ++ sq1 ++ sq2)
  return memoize

main :: IO ()
main = void consTable
```

example logs:

```
Inserting Alive:24 -> Alive:24
Inserting Dead:48 -> Dead:48
Inserting Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24) -> Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24)
Inserting Node1-82(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Dead:48) -> Node1-82(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Dead:48)
Inserting Node1-80(Alive:24, Alive:24, Dead:48, Alive:24) -> Node1-80(Alive:24, Alive:24, Dead:48, Alive:24)
Inserting Node1-89(Alive:24, Alive:24, Dead:48, Dead:48) -> Node1-89(Alive:24, Alive:24, Dead:48, Dead:48)
Inserting Node1-78(Alive:24, Dead:48, Alive:24, Alive:24) -> Node1-78(Alive:24, Dead:48, Alive:24, Alive:24)
Inserting Node1-87(Alive:24, Dead:48, Alive:24, Dead:48) -> Node1-87(Alive:24, Dead:48, Alive:24, Dead:48)
Inserting Node1-85(Alive:24, Dead:48, Dead:48, Alive:24) -> Node1-85(Alive:24, Dead:48, Dead:48, Alive:24)
Inserting Node1-94(Alive:24, Dead:48, Dead:48, Dead:48) -> Node1-94(Alive:24, Dead:48, Dead:48, Dead:48)
Inserting Node1-76(Dead:48, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24) -> Node1-76(Dead:48, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24)
Inserting Node1-85(Dead:48, Alive:24, Alive:24, Dead:48) -> Node1-85(Dead:48, Alive:24, Alive:24, Dead:48)
Inserting Node1-83(Dead:48, Alive:24, Dead:48, Alive:24) -> Node1-83(Dead:48, Alive:24, Dead:48, Alive:24)
Inserting Node1-92(Dead:48, Alive:24, Dead:48, Dead:48) -> Node1-92(Dead:48, Alive:24, Dead:48, Dead:48)
Inserting Node1-81(Dead:48, Dead:48, Alive:24, Alive:24) -> Node1-81(Dead:48, Dead:48, Alive:24, Alive:24)
Inserting Node1-90(Dead:48, Dead:48, Alive:24, Dead:48) -> Node1-90(Dead:48, Dead:48, Alive:24, Dead:48)
Inserting Node1-88(Dead:48, Dead:48, Dead:48, Alive:24) -> Node1-88(Dead:48, Dead:48, Dead:48, Alive:24)
Inserting Node1-97(Dead:48, Dead:48, Dead:48, Dead:48) -> Node1-97(Dead:48, Dead:48, Dead:48, Dead:48)
Inserting Node2-122(Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24), Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24), Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24), Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24)) -> Node2-122(Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24), Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24), Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24), Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24))
Inserting Node2-131(Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24), Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24, Alive:24), Node1-73(Alive:24, Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144), Node1-112(Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144, Dead:72)) -> Node2-41(Node1-121(Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144), Node1-121(Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144), Node1-121(Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144), Node1-112(Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144, Dead:72))
Inserting Node2-95(Node1-121(Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144), Node1-121(Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144), Node1-121(Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144), Node1-114(Alive:144, Alive:144, Dead:72, Alive:144)) -> Node2-95(Node1-121(Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144), Node1-121(Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144), Node1-121(Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144, Alive:144), Node1-114(Alive:144, Alive:144, Dead:72, Alive:144))
```

At this point, everything is inserted properly. The problem is that the hashes are not consistent (For example, Alive going from hash 24 to 144 in the logs). I suspect the initial sq* to suffer from early evaluations. The thunk are not stored with the evaluated data, so the stablenames change. I can I handle this problem ?

Comment: That's just a thing that stable names do sometimes. From [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-Mem-StableName.html), "if two stable names are not equal, then the objects they name may still be equal."

Comment: Do you know any alternative ? I thought they were doing this because of laziness

Comment: You should generally use something that's already evaluated to make a stable name. `do {q <- evaluate a; qn <- makeStableName q; ...}`

Comment: Doesnt work either, I didn't wanted to traverse the entire structure to get the hash, but I guess I have no other option. Thanks

Comment: @GuillaumeBadi Why traverse the whole thing? Put the hash in as a field and then you can compute it at creation by just combining the hashes of the subfields. Or, use two maps (forming one asymmetric bidirectional map): roughly `Key ~> (Level, Key, Key, Key, Key)` and `(Key, Key, Key, Key) ~> Key`. Construction of a node from subnodes checks first whether such a node already exists with the second map. Getting the contents of an existing node goes through the first map.

Comment: @HTNW It works ! Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't understand @HTNW 's suggestion. Could anyone elaborate a bit more, please?